# How to parse large files looking for a word

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

I have some extremely large json files
I am not even really sure if some are even written correctly

Therefore viewing the with a editor is not possible (it freezes vscode etc)

I can view them with `less thefile.json` but I am looking for (all) occurrences of a word and the data that follow them

How can I find these occurrences from the terminal?

For example I want to find all the occurrence of the word `OutputResults` and their value

```
{  "OutputResults": 
     { "first": 0,
       "second": 2
     }
}
```

EDIT:

I am trying

```
cat thefile.json | grep -i '"OutputResults":'

cat thefile.json | grep -A 4 '"OutputResults":'
```

But that shows the whole file, highlighting OutputResults in red. And it is ahuge file so I have to stop it at some point.

How can I just extract the part where OutputResults occur?

Comment: The answer will depend on what "extremely large json files" means. 1Tb?  Not a lot of software/tools can scan that.  Is the size more than 1/2 your memory? If so look for options that use "stream".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're parsing structured text like JSON, use a dedicated tool that understands the structure, as generic text processing tools will depend on cues like newlines and whitespace which are not essential to the structure.

So, [using `jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/), you could get values of all `.OutputResults` keys using something like:

```
jq '.. | select(.OutputResults?) | .OutputResults'
```

For example:

```
% cat foo.json | jq '.. | select(.OutputResults?) | .OutputResults'
{
  "first": 0,
  "second": 2
}
{
  "first": 0,
  "second": 2
}
```

Or if you need the `.OutputResults` as part of the output:

```
% jq '.. | select(.OutputResults?) | {OutputResults}' foo.json
{
  "OutputResults": {
    "first": 0,
    "second": 2
  }
}
{
  "OutputResults": {
    "first": 0,
    "second": 2
  }
}
```

Or with compact output:

```
%  jq '.. | select(.OutputResults?) | {OutputResults}' -c < foo.json
{"OutputResults":{"first":0,"second":2}}
{"OutputResults":{"first":0,"second":2}}
```

---

For reading very large JSON files with `jq`, we have to use its "streaming mode", but the way `jq` does stream makes it much more complicated to use. I think the following `jq` program, obtained by tweaking [the example in `jq` FAQ](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki/FAQ#streaming-json-parser), should work for showing just the values of of `OutputResults` keys:

```
foreach inputs as $in (
  null;
  if has("OutputResults") then null
  else . as $x
  | $in
  | if length != 2 and $x then {"OutputResults": $x}
    elif length != 2 then null
    elif .[0][-2] == "OutputResults" then ($x + {"\(.[0][-1])": "\(.[-1])"})
    else $x
    end
  end;
  select(has("OutputResults")) | .
)
```

Put this in a file, say, `outputresults.jq`, and use it like so:

```
jq -n --stream -f outputresults.jq some-inputjson
```

Comment: I tried the first one and it froze my PC for a while and killed my vscode...  The output of the command was `Killed`

Comment: For _extremely_ large JSON files, `jq` also has a stream mode, but it's annoying to use. See if the update helps.

Comment: Works great!. quick question, to stop it I have to do ctrl-c I suppose?

Comment: @KansaiRobot yes, but generally programs output at a much faster rate than the terminal can display the output, so for large outputs, by the time you press Ctrl-C and the process might already have exited on its own and you're just seeing the terminal catching up on the output.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is what you want. Type `man grep` if you want more info.

Use this:
`grep -a 4 '"OutputResults":' thefile.json`
and it will output something like that:

```json
{  "OutputResults": 
     { "first": 0,
       "second": 2
     }
}
{  "OutputResults": 
     { "first": 5,
       "second": 3
     }
}
{  "OutputResults": 
     { "first": 2,
       "second": 2
     }
}
```

Comment: grep: "OutputResults":: No such file or directory

Comment: what is the `-a` option for? (I read the man and did not get it)

Comment: When I do `cat thefile.json | grep -i  'OutputResults'` I got the whole file but with the words I want in red....

Comment: Now that I think about it, perhaps the reason why it display the whole thing is because the json is not separated by new lines...maybe

Comment: 1. Make sure to write exactly `'"OutputResults":'` (there are single quotes before the double quotes).
2. `-a x` will output x lines after an occurrence of the searched string.
3. Red words is the normal behavior, it highlights the occurrence.
4. Didn't you need the whole file?

Comment: I was hoping to get only the parts with OutputResults and some more lines.

Comment: @KansaiRobot grep does exactly that